# Angular2: cargar componente en router-outlet por nombre

Tags: angularjs-2.0, angular2-template

estoy realizando un tab dinámico en Angular 2

`<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li *ngFor="let tab of ltTabsMenu">
        <a data-toggle="tab" href="#{{tab.idDiv}}">{{tab.title}}</a>
     </li>
 </ul>`

Posteriormente genero los div mediante otro ngFor:

`<div *ngFor="let tab of ltTabsMenu" id="{{tab.idDiv}}" class="tab-pane fade fill">
     <router-outlet name="tab.OutletName"></router-outlet>                                        </div>`

Una vez hecho esto necesito cargar un componente en el router-outlet con el nombre que yo le indique, he probado con lo siguiente pero nada:

```
let navigationExtras: any = {
 outlets: { 'nombre_outlet': ['none'] }
```

};

this._router.navigate(['counter'], navigationExtras);

En definitiva lo que necesito es generar un tab dinámico y cuando el usuario se posicione sobre un tab cargar un componente en en un div independiente, ya que el usuario podrá abrir varios tab y navegar entre ellos sin perder información.

¿Como lo puedo resolver?

Muchas gracias